# CentOS 5.5 - services start

Tags: centos, service, start

Can I know if my service is started on system init or it started by user using service command?

On my service I need to make different logic (into service starter script) if service is started automatically or by user command.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve. What kind of different logic?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but what you should *really* do is make an init script and only start the service with it. Then it shouldn't whether it was started by a user or by init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the users use sudo or they su root i don't think is a way you can tell, but i think you can
do this:

add a command that looks for server uptime - if the uptime is very very low as in is just starting then you can ASSUME that is server startup and you do the logic around it.

```
uptime | awk '{print $3}' # prints the minutes since the host is up
```

Answer (score 1):

If service is `ON` in `chkconfig` list, it is started by init.

If service is `OFF` in `chkconfig` list and service is in started state, then it is started from user level.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your looking for 'chkconfig --list' which will list all the registered services in /etc/init.d/* . Other service commands can be started from /etc/init.d but not be added to chkconfig, from /etc/rc.local, and from /etc/inittab.